# Can't access nodejs from outside network?

Tags: node.js, tcp, portforwarding, fritzbox

I have a Fritzbox 7490 router and have port forwarded (i think) a port 8080.

This port is not open externally for some reason but is accessible through the router ip address.

I set up a nodejs express app that hosts html pages and listens on port 8080

```
app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 8080);
});
```

Then, i enter: routerip:8080 into browser and it works fine.
But if I connect from an external source routerip:8080

I don't get any response.

Online port checkers are saying the address is not accessible, which leads me back to my port forwarding not working correctly.

Setting for Fritzbox port forwarding:

Name: HTTPS-Server
Protocol: TCP
Port to device: 8080 through port 8080
Port requested externally(ipv4): 8080

Enable sharing: True

It then gives me a IPv4 address in the internet with the same port 8080

Which i try, and connects locally, but not externally.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the public IP address of the router (that's different than the private IP address of the router)? The only other logical explanation is that your port forwarding is not working properly or there is another network firewall in the way.  Not much we can do from here to debug it.

Comment: Well, the router says the firewall protection is disabled for this pc. The status says its live, I type in 'what is my ip' into a browser, which i'm assuming is my public router ip address. I use that followed by the port number. I added a rule in the windows defender firewall on the hosting machine.

I'm running out of options? Can isp's block ports or something?

Comment: Some ISPs block some ports on residential internet connections.  Some routers (like mine) have a network log that will let me attempt to connect from the outside at a precise time and then check the logs to see what happened with that request and whether it appears to have arrived at the router or not.  You're going to just have to try to trace the incoming request one step at a time to see where it gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit of a mission.

My isp was blocking port forwarding. Apparently I had a dynamic ip address, but the ip address wasn't changing... DHCP wasn't enabled. I tracerted the public ip address of the router locally and externally and was getting blocked by the isp.

I called, they said port forwarding was a security concern and said they couldn't help.

I double checked the tracert and thought about it for a while. Then called again, said it has to be you guys... They said to pay a little extra and said something about a network change and assigned a static ip. It then worked...

Bit pissed with the extra charge though...

Comment: They are just trying to make people who host servers pay more.  It's how they choose to run their business.  In my locale, you can only get asymmetric home internet that's fast for download, but slow for upload which means servers don't have very good bandwidth for serving content.  Same reason.  If you want symmetric bandwidth, you have to buy a business plan.  Your alternative would be to find a different ISP that doesn't do that.  But, since we don't have very many choices for home internet (it's either a monopoly or oligopoly in most places), we can't always find a choice we like.

Comment: Do you know how isps get into the business? I'm pretty sure they don't actually own the infrastructure, they rent it, right? I imagine from the government (depending on location).

Comment: Well, it depends upon who exactly you're talking about and what country.  Around here (in my regions of the U.S.), Comcast and AT&T are the two main choices and they both install their own wires/fiber to each house.  They build it themselves and they own it.  Because they are an oligopoly, they are subject to some regulations.

Comment: Yeh, I guess it is dependent on company policy and location, oh well, thanks for your help!